# Circular dependency in Cloudformation template between IAM resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I keep hitting circular dependency error in my cloudformation template and not sure how I can eliminate that. I am creating a user and attaching the `IAMManagedPolicy2` to the user.
The policy allows the user to assume two roles, `IAMRole` and `IAMRole2`.
`IAMRole2` requires defining the assume permission for the user. This is probably the reason why I am hitting the circular dependency in my case. Here is how my template looks like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Metadata:
    Generator: "former2"
Description: ""
Resources:
    IAMUser:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::User"
        Properties:
            Path: "/"
            UserName: "sysuser"
            ManagedPolicyArns: 
              - !Ref IAMManagedPolicy2

    IAMGroup:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::Group"
        Properties:
            Path: "/"
            GroupName: "Temp"


    IAMManagedPolicy2:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy"
        Properties:
            ManagedPolicyName: "UserAssumePolicy"
            Path: "/"
            PolicyDocument: !Sub |
                {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                            "Resource": [
                                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/${IAMRole}",
                                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/${IAMRole2}"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }


    IAMRole:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
        Properties:
            Path: "/"
            RoleName: "AddUserToGroupRole"
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: "2012-10-17"
                Statement:
                    -
                        Effect: "Allow"
                        Principal:
                          AWS:
                            - !GetAtt IAMUser.Arn
                        Action:
                          - "sts:AssumeRole"
            MaxSessionDuration: 3600
            ManagedPolicyArns: 
              - !Ref IAMManagedPolicy3
            Description: "Allows Adding users to group"


    IAMRole2:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
        Properties:
            Path: "/"
            RoleName: "AttachGroupPolicyRole"
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: "2012-10-17"
                Statement:
                    -
                        Effect: "Allow"
                        Principal:
                          AWS:
                            - !GetAtt IAMUser.Arn
                          Service:
                            - "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                        Action:
                          - "sts:AssumeRole"
            MaxSessionDuration: 3600
            ManagedPolicyArns: 
              - !Ref IAMManagedPolicy
            Description: ""
            Tags: 
              - 
                Key: "event"
                Value: "troopers"

    IAMManagedPolicy:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy"
        Properties:
            ManagedPolicyName: "AttachGroupPolicy"
            Path: "/"
            PolicyDocument: !Sub |
                {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": "iam:AttachGroupPolicy",
                            "Resource": [
                                "arn:aws:iam::*:group/${IAMGroup}"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }

    IAMManagedPolicy3:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy"
        Properties:
            ManagedPolicyName: "AddUserToGroup"
            Path: "/"
            PolicyDocument: !Sub |
                {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": "iam:AddUserToGroup",
                            "Resource": [
                                "arn:aws:iam::*:group/${IAMGroup}"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Can someone help me point out the changes to eliminate the circular dependency and get the template to work,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are hardcoding the role names (`AddUserToGroupRole` and `AttachGroupPolicyRole`), you must **use the names directly** to overcome the circular dependency problem:

```
    IAMManagedPolicy2:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy"
        Properties:
            ManagedPolicyName: "UserAssumePolicy"
            Path: "/"
            PolicyDocument: !Sub |
                {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                            "Resource": [
                                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/AddUserToGroupRole",
                                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/AttachGroupPolicyRole"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
```